# Object references and cache

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function GetAllProducts() which fetches all products from a database and stores it in the cache for future requests. This works fine, but if I then call the function e.g. ProductSearchResults = GetAllProducts(), and then modify ProductSearchResults variable, this also modifies the cache, which is very important this never happens, as the cache affects the whole website.

I understand this is because both ProductSearchResults and the cache now have the same reference, but how do I solve the problem? Is there something that I can put in GetAllProducts() to ensure the cache always uses its own value?

```
 Public Shared Function GetAllProducts() As ProductCollection

        Dim Products As New ProductCollection()

        If IsNothing(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("ProductData")) Then

            '////// Database code to get products goes here //////

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("ProductData", Products, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero)
        End If
        Products = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("ProductData")

        Return Products

    End Function

 Public Shared Function SearchProducts(ByVal SearchText As String) As ProductCollection

        Dim ProductSearchResults As ProductCollection = Nothing

        If SearchText <> "" Then

            SearchText = SearchText.ToLower()

            Dim Keywords As New ArrayList()
            Keywords.AddRange(SearchText.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

            ProductSearchResults = GetAllProducts()

            For i As Integer = 0 To Keywords.Count - 1

                For j As Integer = ProductSearchResults.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    If ProductSearchResults(j).ProductName.ToLower.Contains(Keywords(i)) = False Then
                        ProductSearchResults.RemoveAt(j)
                    End If
                Next

            Next

        End If

        Return ProductSearchResults

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are essentially returning a collection of pointers to the object thats in the cache. You could implement IClonable on your object and have a Function that returns a new collection with cloned objects.

```
Public Function GetClonedObjects() As ProductCollection

Dim myCollection As New List(Of MyObject)

For Each item as Product in GetProducts()
   myCollection.Add(item.Clone)
Loop

Return myCollection

End Function
```

Or Create a property to hold a cloned copy of the collection

```
    Private _clonedProducts As ProductCollection = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property ClonedProducts As ProductCollection
      Get
        If _clonedProducts Is Nothing Then
          _clonedProducts = New ProductCollection
          For Each item As Product In GetAllProducts()
            _clonedProducts.Add(item.Clone())
          Next
        End If
        Return _clonedProducts
      End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I have got it working but it has really slowed down my application. The page takes 30+ seconds to load now. GetAllProducts() contains over 1000 products and is being called a lot of times through out my application which is why I am caching it. Each time it is being called it is cloning the collection each time. Is there a way I can just clone the collection once and cache it, rather then cloning every time GetAllProducts() is called?

Comment: Code updated to show how to create a local cloned collection (and only have to do the cloning once). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh, and as this is ASP.Net, you probably want to store what I have shown as a local variable, into either Application State or Session State based on your scope.